# How to append row and column number bands to a geotiff file?

Tags: geotiff-tiff

I'm looking for a way to append to a geotiff file: (i) a band giving the row number for each pixel and (ii) a band giving the column number for each pixel. Preferably a command line tool that can be integrated into a linux bash script.

Comment: Feels like an unnecessary exercise because location of each pixel is defined by the file format but of course you can do that if you want.